# scala typeclass extension/generalization initialization

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, typeclass

I ran into a weird and puzzling NPE. Consider the following usecase:
Writing a generic algorithm (binary search in my case), where you'd want to generalize the type, but need some extras.

e.g: maybe you want to cut a range in half, and you need a generic `half` or `two` "consts".

`Integral` typeclass is not enough, since it only offers `one` and `zero`, so I came up with:

```
trait IntegralConsts[N] {
  val tc: Integral[N]
  val two = tc.plus(tc.one,tc.one)
  val four = tc.plus(two,two)
}

object IntegralConsts {
  implicit def consts[N : Integral] = new IntegralConsts[N] {
    override val tc = implicitly[Integral[N]]
  }
}
```

and used it as follows:

```
def binRangeSearch[N : IntegralConsts]( /* irrelevant args */ ) = {
  val consts = implicitly[IntegralConsts[N]]
  val math = consts.tc

  // some irrelevant logic, which contain expressions like:

  val halfRange = math.quot(range, consts.two)

  // ...
}
```

In runtime, this throws a puzzling `NullPointerException` on this line: `val two = tc.plus(tc.one,tc.one)`.
As a workaround, I just added `lazy` to the typeclass' `val`s, and it all worked out:

```
trait IntegralConsts[N] {
  val tc: Integral[N]
  lazy val two = tc.plus(tc.one,tc.one)
  lazy val four = tc.plus(two,two)
}
```

But I would want to know why I got this weird NPE. Initialization order should be known, and `tc` should have already been instantiated when reaching `val two ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Initialization order should be known, and `tc` should have already been
>   instantiated when reaching `val two`

Not according to the specification. What really happens is that while constructing the anonymous class, first `IntegralConsts[T]` will be initialized, and *only then* will the overriding of `tc` be evacuated in the derived anon class, which is why you're experiencing the `NullPointerException`.

The [specification section §5.1 (Templates)](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates) says:

> ### Template Evaluation
>
> Consider a template `sc with mt1 with mtn { stats }`.
>
> If this is the template of a trait then its mixin-evaluation consists of an evaluation of the statement sequence stats.
>
> If this is not a template of a trait, then its evaluation consists of the following steps:
>
> - First, the **superclass constructor `sc` is evaluated**.
> - Then, all base classes in the template's linearization up to the template's superclass denoted by `sc` are mixin-evaluated. Mixin-evaluation happens in reverse order of occurrence in the linearization.
> - Finally the statement sequence `stats` is evaluated.

We can verify this by looking at the compiled code with `-Xprint:typer`:

```
final class $anon extends AnyRef with IntegralConsts[N] {
  def <init>(): <$anon: IntegralConsts[N]> = {
    $anon.super.<init>();
    ()
  };
  private[this] val tc: Integral[N] = scala.Predef.implicitly[Integral[N]](evidence$1);
  override <stable> <accessor> def tc: Integral[N] = $anon.this.tc
};
```

We see that first, `super.<init>` is invoked, and only then is the `val tc` initialized.

Adding to that, lets look at "[Why is my abstract or overridden val null?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html)":

> A ‘strict’ or ‘eager’ val is one which is not marked lazy.
>
> In the absence of “early definitions” (see below), initialization of
>   strict vals is done in the following order:
>
> - Superclasses are fully initialized before subclasses.
> - Otherwise, in declaration order.
>
> Naturally when a `val` is overridden, it is not initialized more than once ... This is not the case: **an overridden val will appear to be null during the construction of superclasses, as will an abstract val.**

We can also verify this by passing the `-Xcheckinit` flag to `scalac`:

```
> set scalacOptions := Seq("-Xcheckinit")                                                                      
[info] Defining *:scalacOptions                                                                                
[info] The new value will be used by compile:scalacOptions                                                     
[info] Reapplying settings...                                                                                  
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/C:/)                                                        
> console
> :pa // paste code here
defined trait IntegralConsts
defined module IntegralConsts
binRangeSearch: [N](range: N)(implicit evidence$2: IntegralConsts[N])Unit

scala> binRangeSearch(100)
scala.UninitializedFieldError: Uninitialized field: <console>: 16
        at IntegralConsts$$anon$1.tc(<console>:16)
        at IntegralConsts$class.$init$(<console>:9)
        at IntegralConsts$$anon$1.<init>(<console>:15)
        at IntegralConsts$.consts(<console>:15)
        at .<init>(<console>:10)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
```

As you've noted, since this is an anonymous class, adding the `lazy` to the definition avoids the initialization quirk altogether. An alternative would be to use early definition:

```
object IntegralConsts {
  implicit def consts[N : Integral] = new  {
    override val tc = implicitly[Integral[N]]
  } with IntegralConsts[N]
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. For some reason, I was under the impression that an abstract `val` should be instantiated eagerly. Another option is to declare `tc` as abstract `def`, and `override lazy val` in anonymous class (since `lazy val`s are essentially `def`s...)

Comment: @giladhoch Glad it helped! The part about initialization can get a little tricky. I think one of the I like less is that all of these workarounds rely on convention, since other devs can get bitten by it.